# What is the purpose of this namespace?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, c-preprocessor, inline-namespaces

In Boost 1.55, `current_function.hpp` reads something like this:

```
namespace boost
{
namespace detail
{
inline void current_function_helper()
{

#if defined(__GNUC__) || (defined(__MWERKS__) && (__MWERKS__ >= 0x3000)) || (defined(__ICC) && (__ICC >= 600)) || defined(__ghs__)

# define BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION __PRETTY_FUNCTION__

#elif ...

#endif

}    
} // namespace detail
} // namespace boost
```

Why did the author even bother writing those namespaces?

Comment: consistancy of encapsulation, so that everything that is relevant is in relevant namespace, not just freeroaming function

Comment: @Creris but this encapsulation would not affect in any way an user of the file, am I right?

Comment: @qdii I didn't get that

Comment: I meant, the presence of the (inline or not) namespaces don't affect the macro definition in any way, or is there sth new in C++11 here?

Comment: boost::detail::current_function_helper is not a part of the public interface of the library. However it is visible and anybody using 'detail' should be ready for implementation changes.

Comment: @qdii That's not an inline namespace, it's an inline function definition.  I think you mean nested namespace.  Note that inline namespace means something different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`detail` namespaces help to avoid polluting the official ones with internal functions or classes the user doesn't need to know of.

Modern IDEs parse Header files and provide code completion, that is, suggestions for names if you start to write something like `boost::c`. That would be quite unusable if internal algorithms such as e.g. `copy_pod_nontrivial` would also be listed. 
Moreover, a typo could lead to a call to an internal function or a declaration of an object of an internal class type. That is definitely not what we want.

A more technical reason for this is ADL: Some functions are found by the type of their arguments (template arguments for function templates are also involved); That can cause name lookup to search for names in the official namespace. If helper functions (or classes) are declared within it, this may cause problems with overload resolution.

Users should never (need to) use those internal functions, so if you see user code that accesses a `detail`-like namespace you should be on guard.

Comment: Having some nice code completion in an IDE, should be no reason for an extra namespace.

Comment: This is just a concrete example. The user shall generally not see those entities in any way, whether it is an IDE feature or name lookup.